# Backtrack 5 and Virtualbox on Windows 7

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, backtrack

I'm trying to install backtrack linux on virtualbox on windows 7 as the host machine. I'm trying to follow this tutorial (written for mac): 
http://www.backtrack-linux.org/wiki/index.php/VirtualBox_Install

I downloaded backtrack 5 R2 64 bit and I'm trying to install it. When I power on the virtual image, i get the following error:

```
VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration has been enabled, but is not operational. 
Your 64-bit guest will fail to detect a 64-bit CPU and will not be able to boot.

Please ensure that you have enabled VT-x/AMD-V properly in the BIOS of your host computer.
```

I then continue with installation. It eventually tells me that I'm using an i686 cpu and that I need to use a 64bit cpu. I have a 64bit core i5 cpu. What's the issue?

Comment: Is VT-x and AMD-v enabled in your BIOS as what you posted may of answered your question :)

Comment: Why not just boot a backtrack live CD or create a very small partition for it and install it to the hard drive? Backtrack has a lot of tools for networking that might be a headache to use from a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I figured it out.

Basically, I had to go to the bios and trigger something called "Intel Virtualization technology". I didn't make the connection that this was the same thing as VT-x... I'm sure that it's probably called many different things in many different BIOS's.

Comment: VT-x stands for just that.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve had BT5 running without the need for VT-x as my BIOS doesn’t support it, you can enable this in BIOS if supported or try VMware too as that’s a better virtualisor in my opinion.